# Restoring a database results in error

Tags: database

I downloaded a database backup from the craft back-end. I've tried to restore it via PHPMyAdmin and MySQL workbench, and I get the following errors:

`ERROR 1227 (42000) at line 18: Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER, SYSTEM_VARIABLES_ADMIN or SESSION_VARIABLES_ADMIN privilege(s) for this operation`

At line 18 in the SQL file:

`SET @@SESSION.SQL_LOG_BIN= 0;`

Is there any way I can get around this so I can restore this database? I'm desperate right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the [Solution.](https://help.poralix.com/articles/mysql-access-denied-you-need-the-super-privilege-for-this-operation) Clearing a couple of lines from the SQL file made it work.